# Get camera focal length as scalar value in shader node

Tags: node-editor, shaders

How can I obtain the active camera's focal length (or any other scalar property) as an input to a shader node's scalar value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At its simplest:

- Right-click in the *Focal Length* property-field of the camera, and 'Copy as New Driver'
- Create an *Input > Value node* in your tree
- Right-click in the *Value* field, and 'Paste Driver'.